# How to get tasks id of Django Periodic Task Object [django-celery-beat]

Tags: python-3.x, django, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

I'm new using Django and celery. I'm using django admin panel to launch the task directly by selecting each individual PeriodicTask model object. I need to get the ID of the task selected.

[image]

I have something like this:

from django_celery_beat.models import PeriodicTask

get_task = PeriodicTask.objects.get(id=**[NumericID]**)

Comment: were you able to get periodic task id ?